# Unix script to count line between pattern of output

Tags: grep, wc

I am trying to write a unix code where I will be to count no of rows between (ie here 2)

two `"|DATE and TIME         | XXXXXX |"`

Is there any method I can use with combination of egrap and wc -l

Output:

```
|-------------------------------|

|DATE and TIME         | XXXXXX |

|-------------------------------|

| 21-NOV-2012 15:56:51 | 1259   |

| 21-NOV-2012 15:56:51 | 1364   |

|-------------------------------|

|DATE and TIME         | XXXXXX |

|-------------------------------|

| 21-NOV-2012 16:06:55 | 1259   |

| 21-NOV-2012 16:06:55 | 1364   |

|-------------------------------|
```

Answer (score 0):

if the expected result is 9 (since there are empty lines in your example, I don't know if they should be counted):

```
awk '/DATE and TIME/&&!f{f=1;next;}/DATE and TIME/&&f{print x;exit;}f{x++}' file
```

Comment: No, expected result was either 2 or 4.

Comment: @Cœur there are nine lines between the two pattern matching lines in the question's input. So it works. If there is need for matching a second pattern into these lines, it should be described in question.

Comment: @thanasisp that's my interpretation of `ie here 2` in the question.